# How to check if GA4 or Universal Analytics is installed?

Tags: javascript, analytics

I'm trying to detect on websites using Javascript if they have the new GA4 installed or the old Universal Analytics.
While for UA detection I can use `typeof(ga) !== "undefined"`, not sure how to do this for GA4.

Based on information [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11150547?hl=en): Seems to be using also **ga**? Any other difference that we can use on client side?

Answer (score 0):

hy,
we use to do it like this for GA4:

```
if(typeof gtag === 'function' ){
        gtag('event', 'myeventname',{
            'event_category': 'myeventcategory'
        });
}
```

please note that this will only work if you have GA4 tracking code installed directly in your page. if you use google tag manager, this won't work.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The tag installation instructions include a line of code that defines a gtag function every time, whether the gtag.js is loaded or not: `function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}`. That being the case, gtag will always be a function.

Answer (score -1):

For detecting Google Analytics 4 (GA4) on a website, you can check for the existence of the gtag function, as GA4 uses the gtag.js library. Here's an example:

```
if (typeof gtag === "function") {
  console.log("Google Analytics 4 is installed on this website.");
} else {
  console.log("Google Analytics 4 is not installed on this website.");
}
```

Note that if both GA4 and Universal Analytics (UA) are installed on the same website, you will need to use the gtag function to send data to GA4 and the ga function to send data to UA. In that case, you will also need to make sure to send the data to the correct property by specifying the correct tracking ID.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The tag installation instructions include a line of code that defines a gtag function every time, whether the gtag.js is loaded or not: `function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}`. That being the case, gtag will always be a function.